# Wifi on a Mac Pro 4,1

Tags: network, wifi, mac-pro

I recently bought a Mac Pro 4,1. Flashed it to 5,1 and such.

The thing is, it doesn't seem to have any WiFi card. It doesn't recognize a WiFi USB that I have here lying around that I bought for my main PC which has Windows installed. I am not sure if these machines came with a WiFi card in all of its configurations.

I don't need AirDrop or anything like that, since I bought it to tinker with it (I love retrocomputing) and to get myself used to the Apple Mac OS system. So I don't really think I will need the best WiFi card out there. Do you know if there is something that should work not doing it? (Like detecting the USB WiFi).

If this is the expected behaviour, can someone redirect me to a cheap WiFi card? I just don't want to have the Ethernet cable around because it is uncomfortable in the position I have the router in my house.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you visually inspected for the WiFi card being fitted? Behind the front CPU fan assembly - http://www.macvidcards.com/wifi-and-bluetooth-card-installation-in-a-41-or-51.html You can buy them for a few bucks on eBay these days. If it's physically present, you can check for recognition in About This Mac… > System Report > Wifi

Comment: Ok, is missing, I can see the port but not any card. i guess I'll take a look at ebay although I don't really know what to look for exactly, some of them seem to be very expensive and I am afraid of buying something I don't need. Maybe they are newer and provide more functionality.

Comment: see https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2047675.m570.l1313&_nkw=Mac+Pro+4%2C1+5%2C1+Apple+WiFi+&_sacat=0 The cabling [unless someone's removed it] should already be in place - check first if you buy one without.

Comment: Yep, there are three cables coming out and the slot is intact there, so... I think I will only need the card.

Comment: Some Mac Pro models (don't know about 4,1) originally had WiFi as an extra-cost add-on.

Comment: Do you think I would need only a card or also any cables? Some of the cards seem to come with no cables and other have a couple of them coming out of the card itself - [Photo of my Mac Pro](https://imgur.com/a/VqQBCda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WiFI board on Mac Pro [cheesegraters] was an optional purchase.
They are easy to find on eBay as DIY add-ins. They are not difficult to fit, but you need to strip the machine a bit to get to the location on the motherboard.

Fortunately, this is a bit easier on the 4,1 than earlier Mac Pros. you can reach it if you take the processor tray out.

[image]

[image]
<sub>Images from the official Apple Service Source manual for the Mac Pro 4,1</sub>

The wires & screws *should* be in place already, even if no board was originally shipped with it - but it's wise to check first.

Example [eBay selection [UK]](https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2047675.m570.l1313&_nkw=Mac%20Pro%204%2C1%205%2C1%20Apple%20WiFi%20&_sacat=0)
Bluetooth was optional too, which is why you often find these boards being sold in pairs.
Apple at the time designated these as 'AirPort Extreme' cards, back when 'WiFi' wasn't as ubiquitous a term as it since became.